# RSpec mocking a nested model in Rails - ActionController problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mocking, rspec

I am having a problem in RSpec when my mock object is asked for a URL by the ActionController. The URL is a Mock one and not a correct resource URL.

I am running RSpec 1.3.0 and Rails 2.3.5

Basically I have two models. Where a subject has many notes.

```
class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :title
  has_many :notes
end

class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :title
  belongs_to :subject
end
```

My **routes.rb** file nests these two resources as such:

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|
  map.resources :subjects, :has_many => :notes
end
```

The **NotesController.rb** file looks like this:

```
class NotesController < ApplicationController
  # POST /notes
  # POST /notes.xml
  def create
    @subject = Subject.find(params[:subject_id])
    @note = @subject.notes.create!(params[:note])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to(@subject) }
    end
  end
end
```

Finally this is my RSpec spec which should simply post my mocked objects to the NotesController and be executed... which it does:

```
it "should create note and redirect to subject without javascript" do
  # usual rails controller test setup here
  subject = mock(Subject)
  Subject.stub(:find).and_return(subject)

  notes_proxy = mock('association proxy', { "create!" => Note.new })
  subject.stub(:notes).and_return(notes_proxy)
  post :create, :subject_id => subject, :note => { :title => 'note title', :body => 'note body' }
end
```

The problem is that when the **RSpec post** method is called.

The NotesController correctly handles the Mock Subject object, and **create!** the new **Note** object. However when the NoteController#Create method tries to **redirect_to** I get the following error:

> NoMethodError in 'NotesController should create note and redirect to subject without javascript'
>   undefined method `spec_mocks_mock_url' for #<NotesController:0x1034495b8>

Now this is caused by a bit of Rails trickery that passes an ActiveRecord object (@subject, in our case, which isn't ActiveRecord but a Mock object), eventually to **url_for** who passes all the options to the Rails' Routing, which then determines the URL.

My question is how can I mock Subject so that the correct options are passed so that I my test passes.

I've tried passing in **:controller => 'subjects'** options but no joy.

Is there some other way of doing this?

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at `mock_model`, which is added by rspec-rails to make it easier to mock ActiveRecord objects. According to the [api docs](http://rspec.rubyforge.org/rspec-rails/1.2.7.1/):

`mock_model: Creates a mock object instance for a model_class with common methods stubbed out.`

I'm not sure if it takes care of `url_for`, but it's worth a try.

---

***Update, 2018-06-05***:

[As of rspec 3](http://rspec.info/blog/2014/05/notable-changes-in-rspec-3/#extracted-activemodel-mocks-support):

> `mock_model` and `stub_model` have been extracted into the [rspec-activemodel-mocks gem](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-activemodel-mocks).

Comment: Fantastic, that worked fine. I've been bashing my head with the problem for a couple of hours and solved the other issues but have been a bit blinkered. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In case zetetic's idea doesn't work out, you can always say `Subject.new` and then stub out `to_param` and whatever else you might need faked for your example.